# Google Container Engine (GKE): "Hello Wordpress" tutorial not working (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to setup example from [Running Wordpress with a Single Pod](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-wordpress).

- I've done [Before You Begin](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/before-you-begin) section:

$ gcloud config list

```
[compute]
zone = europe-west1-c
[core]
account = user@email.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = com-project-default
```

- I've done the steps from the tutorial:

  "Step 1: Create your cluster" [logs here](http://pastebin.com/STBtnuxC)

  "Step 2: Create your pod" [logs here](http://pastebin.com/4Gv0nJrF)

  "Step 3: Allow external traffic" [logs here](http://pastebin.com/ugJ9gztX)
- More logs:

  $kubectl get pods - [log (toggle text wrapping)](http://pastebin.com/wNQ8T5Fp)

  $gcloud compute firewall-rules list - [log](http://pastebin.com/ayGwRveq)

So, when I try to connect to http://104.155.7.213/ I'm receiving "This web page is not available: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`".

I tried to add "`Allow HTTP traffic`" explicitly to the node in Compute Engine VMs dashboard and also I tried to use "`kubectl run`" instead of deprecated "`kubectl run-container`", but it doesn't help. Also sometimes I'm receiving "`last termination: exit code 2`" (`1` or `2`) in "`message`" column when run "`kubectl get pods`" (but not this time)`

Info:

[GKE from June 10, 2015](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes)

$ kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"0", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v0.18.1", GitCommit:"befd1385e5af5f7516f75a27a2628272bb9e9f36", GitTreeState:"clean"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"0", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v0.18.2", GitCommit:"1f12b893876ad6c41396222693e37061f6e80fe1", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

$ gcloud version

```
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.64
alpha 2015.06.02
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
compute 2015.06.09
core 2015.06.09
core-nix 2015.06.02
dns 2015.06.02
gcloud 2015.06.09
gcutil-msg 2015.06.09
gsutil 4.13
gsutil-nix 4.12
kubectl 
kubectl-linux-x86_64 0.18.1
preview 2015.06.09
sql 2015.06.09
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the container directly using the node VM's IP address, you need to specify a host port in addition to a container port, e.g. 
`kubectl run-container wordpress --image=tutum/wordpress --port=80 --hostport=80`

Alternatively, you can access wordpress via the proxy running on the master by running `kubectl proxy` and then pointing your web browser at `http://localhost:8001/api/v1beta3/proxy/namespaces/default/pods/wordpress-3gaq6`.